# Why i am having a maximum recursion depth exceeded error

Tags: python, arrays, list, sorting, binary-search

I am trying to apply the Binary Search algorithm (the recursive way) and I'm having this error

```
def BinarySearchRec(tab, x):
    mid = len(tab) // 2
    if len(tab) == 0:
        return False
    if tab[mid] > x:
        return BinarySearchRec(tab[:mid], x)
    elif tab[mid] < x:
        return BinarySearchRec(tab[mid:], x)
    else:
        return mid
```

I tried to 1 and retrive one when i call the function back but didn't work on all cases

Comment: Please update your question with an example of how you call your function when it exceeds maximum recursion depth.

Comment: Add a print statement or use a debugger to monitor the value of `mid` from call to call. You'll see that `tab[:mid]` and `tab[mid:]` eventually are the same as `tab`, so your recursion isn't progressing.

Comment: When the length of the list is 1 and you try to slice `tab[mid:]`, you will get the same list, which causes the recursion to fail.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "I tried to 1 and retrive one when i call the function back but didn't work on all cases" This isn't understandable. Please read [ask] and [mre], and clearly show: how do you call the function in order to cause a problem? What should happen for that input? What does happen instead, and how is that different?

Answer (score 1):

When `mid=0` and `tab[mid] < x`, the code gets stuck because `BinarySearchRec(tab[mid:], x)` will loop forever with the same inputs: `(tab[mid:],x) -> (tab[0:],x) -> (tab,x)` .

As a proof, you can try the following example:

```
tab = [1]
x   = 2
BinarySearchRec(tab, x)
# recursion error raised
```

The easiest solution is to make sure that the array `tab` decreases in size every time you perform recursion:

```
def BinarySearchRec(tab, x):
    mid = len(tab) // 2
    if len(tab) == 0:
        return False
    if tab[mid] > x:
        return BinarySearchRec(tab[:mid-1], x)
    elif tab[mid] < x:
        return BinarySearchRec(tab[mid+1:], x)
    else:
        return mid

tab = [1]
x   = 2
BinarySearchRec(tab, x)
# now it works
```

In the new code, the `tab` array is trimmed using either `mid+1` or `mid-1`, since we can discard `mid` as a solution when `tab[mid] != x`. This makes sure that `tab` always decreases at least one element in size, and hence the code does not crash. Cheers,